# Вид сказуемого.

Tags: синтаксис

**Каждый из них решал этот вопрос.**
Какое тут сказуемое: простое глагольное или составное именное?

Answer (score 3):

В именном сказуемом основное лексическое значение заключено НЕ В ГЛАГОЛЕ, глагол (даже полнозначный) играет роль связки и выражает грамматическое значение. В этом предложении, на мой взгляд, основное лексическое значение заключено именно в слове "решал". Т.е. сказуемое простое глагольное. Но, видимо, у Вас еще один вопрос: граница сказуемого -  *решал* или *решал вопрос*. Я считаю, что сказуемое *решал* (вопрос, задачу, нашу судьбу). Нет спаянности элементов. нельзя заменить одним словом. В противоположном по смыслу предложении: каждый из них *задавал вопрос* сказуемое будет "задавал вопрос", т.е. спрашивал.

Answer (score 1):

"Этот" - именная часть???? А "решал вопрос" связка к "этому"??? EkaterinaKas... -  это фурор в лингвистике!!! Если Вы нашли, где "это читали", то делитесь скорее...

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно справедливо: сказуемое простое глагольное. Решать можно и задачу. Хотя в составном глагольном сказуемом  глагол "решать" может выступать как вспомогательный. Но, наверное, в неделимом сочетании.

Answer (score 0):

**Каждый из них решал этот вопрос.** Сказуемое здесь **составное именное** ***"решал этот вопрос"***. Устойчивое выражение **"решать вопрос"** выступает здесь в роли связки и выражает грамматическое значение, а переменный компонент "этот" является именной частью, выражающей основное значение. Ср.: Каждый из них РЕШАЛ (этот, сложный, волнующий всех, проблемный и т.д.)ВОПРОС.
  Простым глагольным сказуемым выражение "решать вопрос" может быть в примерах типа :***На совещании при директоре решали вопрос о посещаемости***. (Ср.: ***думали, говорили о посещаемости***, выражение "решали вопрос" цельное, нерасчленённое, его можно заменить одним глаголом). 
Вообще, если структура устойчивого сочетания разрушается, то и синтаксическая его роль может измениться. В нашем случае из простого глагольного, каковым обычно является устойчивое выражение, сказуемое превратилось в составное именное из-за вставленного компонента "этот".

Comment: В предложенном коротком предложении (не будем додумывать контекст)для меня основным словом все-таки является слово РЕШАЛ.  (Думал о вопросе, искал пути решения вопроса). ИМенно в нем заключено и лексическое, и грамматическое  значение. 

Правда и то, что определение границ сказуемого во многих случаях вопрос неоднозначный.

Comment: Уважаю Ваше мнение. Не спорю. Просто предлагаю своё решение. Я что-то  читала о таких случаях. Запомнился тот факт, что устойчивые выражения могут быть связкой в составном именном сказуемом, если выражение расчленено. Вспомнить бы, где читала... Поищу. Интересно.

Comment: Сказуемое в данном случае не может быть составным именным: основное лексическое значение здесь сосредоточено на глаголе (решал), а не на имени (вопрос). Попробуйте убрать глагол. Что останется?. Это простое глагольное сказуемое, выраженное неделимым сочетанием. Ларf очень хорошо это объяснила.

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательно ответ Ларf. Она как раз не считает, что сказуемое здесь выражено неделимым сочетанием. Она предлагает считать сказуемым "решал".

Comment: К тому же еще и пропустила (просмотрела) местоимение ЭТОТ (вопрос). Простое глагольное сказуемое. ВОПРОС - прямое дополнение. ЭТОТ - определение.

Answer (score 0):

"Решал" - простое глагольное сказуемое.Состоит из одного глагола прошедшего времени.

Answer (score 0):

"Решал" - простое глагольное сказуемое.Состоит из одного глагола прошедшего времени.